# How can I insert multiple numbers into an array at once from user input in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a Program that allows me to insert numbers into an array.

But I want to insert four of them at once.

I want the program to behave like this:

```
Please enter the amount of sets you want: 2

Please enter the set of four numbers: 3 4 1 2

Please enter the set of four numbers: 2 6 8 4

You entered:

3 4 1 2

2 6 8 4
```

and I know how to output the numbers but I am stuck with the input because I can only get it to work if I do it like this

```
 Please enter the amount of sets you want: 2

    Please enter the set of four numbers: 3 
4 
1 
2

    Please enter the set of four numbers: 2 
6 
8 
4

You entered:

3 4 1 2

2 6 8 4
```

How can I insert a set of four numbers into an array from the user input separated by a space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you doing the input right now? With `scanf` and the `%d` format? You can still use it, it doesn't matter what kind of space is between the numbers, all white-space is treated the same. And if you *always* expect four numbers, then why not read all four in a single `scanf` call, as `scanf("%d %d %d %d", ...)`?

Comment: You should show a [mcve] of your current code.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily enter several values
If your code looks like this:

```
scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);
scanf("%d", &numbers[1]);
scanf("%d", &numbers[2]);
```

You can easily enter for example 3 numbers like this:
one by one

```
5
6
7
```

or in one line

```
5 6 7
```

due to the fact that they are separated by spaces, it perceives them as sequential input

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like,

```
scanf( "%i %i %i %i", &valOne, &valTwo, &valThree, &valFour);
```